# Derived column expression only capture 10 characters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transformation, ssis-2012, sql-server-2012-datatools

I am new to SSIS and I have searched to find the solution to this question.  Any help is most appreciated!

I have a flat file with data defined as dt_wstr, to change the datatype I am using a data conversion to set the [column] to dt_str(50)

I am also using a derived column  - to add as a new column: The goal is write an expression

I have a [column] which is defined as 11 characters

My question is how do I write an expression to only capture 10 characters, and anything greater than 10 I want to change the [column] to -1 else (dt_I8) [column]

I've tried:

```
FINDSTRING([Column],"9999999999",1) == 10 ? -1 : (DT_I8)TRIM([Column]) 

FINDSTRING([Column],"9999999999",1) > 10 ? -1 : (DT_I8)TRIM([Column]) 

LEN([Column]) == 10 ? -1 : (DT_I8)[column]

SUBSTRING( [Copy of Member ID] ,1,10)
```

The package runs without errors however the results in the table are not correct, the column with more than 10 characters are not showing up in the table

I am using visual studio 2012

Thank you Dawana

Comment: Are you trying to write a [`CASE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) expression?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why your substring attempt didn't work, but this would return the first 10 characters of `column`:

```
LEFT(column,10)
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231081(v=sql.110).aspx